# Extracting elements of the largest monotonically increasing/ decreasing sequences in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where I have values for my 'linear' variable and there 30 different groups. I want to calculate/count the elements of the maximum increasing/decreasing sequences for each group in the dataframe.

```
Linear | Series | Basal
91 | Night 1 | decrease       
78 | Night 1 | decrease
82 | Night 1 | increase
75 | Night 1 | decrease
71 | Night 1 | decrease
73 | Night 1 | increase
76 | Night 1 | increase
103 | Night 1 | increase
112 | Night 1 | increase
.
.
.
```

Group (column: Series)
The results/output should be where I want to save two vectors like this:

```
Night 1: night1_inc <- c(73,76,102,112)
Night 1: night1_dec <- c(91,78)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your expected output. Why do you only report the first decrease `c(91, 78)`. What about the decrease `c(75, 71)`?

Comment: I made a small mistake. I don't report the first increase/decrease. I am trying to report the largest increase/decrease

Comment: But `c(91, 78)` and `c(75, 71)` are both length 2 decreases. How do you decide which one to choose?

Comment: Ok. I again apologize for overlooking this. In that case report both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure on your expected output format, but perhaps you can do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df.res <- df %>%
    group_by(Series) %>%
    mutate(grp = cumsum(c(0, diff(Basal)) != 0)) %>%
    add_count(Basal, grp) %>%
    group_by(Basal) %>%
    filter(n == max(n))
df.res
## A tibble: 8 x 5
## Groups:   Basal [2]
#  Linear Series  Basal      grp     n
#   <int> <fct>   <fct>    <int> <int>
#1     91 Night 1 decrease     0     2
#2     78 Night 1 decrease     0     2
#3     75 Night 1 decrease     2     2
#4     71 Night 1 decrease     2     2
#5     73 Night 1 increase     3     4
#6     76 Night 1 increase     3     4
#7    103 Night 1 increase     3     4
#8    112 Night 1 increase     3     4
```

This will return a `data.frame`/`tibble`, with a `grp` column marking the different increase/decrease groups and `n` returning the number of increases/decreases in that group. It is then easy to filter for those entries that below to the *largest* increase/decrease group. In the case of ties, it will report all groups that have the same maximal increase/decrease.

Depending on what you'd like to do with the data downstream, you could e.g. split `df.res` by `grp`

```
df.res %>%
    split(., .$grp)
#$`0`
## A tibble: 2 x 5
## Groups:   Basal [1]
#  Linear Series  Basal      grp     n
#   <int> <fct>   <fct>    <int> <int>
#1     91 Night 1 decrease     0     2
#2     78 Night 1 decrease     0     2
#
#$`2`
## A tibble: 2 x 5
## Groups:   Basal [1]
#  Linear Series  Basal      grp     n
#   <int> <fct>   <fct>    <int> <int>
#1     75 Night 1 decrease     2     2
#2     71 Night 1 decrease     2     2
#
#$`3`
## A tibble: 4 x 5
## Groups:   Basal [1]
#  Linear Series  Basal      grp     n
#   <int> <fct>   <fct>    <int> <int>
#1     73 Night 1 increase     3     4
#2     76 Night 1 increase     3     4
#3    103 Night 1 increase     3     4
#4    112 Night 1 increase     3     4
```